# Update nuget packages using gulp

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, nuget

I am able to restore nuget packgages in a visual studio solution using restore method in gulp-nuget package.
But update method is not found with gulp-nuget.
Is there any other way to accomplish this via gulp ?
I need to update only the packages those are in my private nuget repository.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to accomplish this via gulp ?

I am afraid you could not accomplish this via gulp. Because there is no such option `gulp-nuget update` for gulp-nuget. You can check the [gulp-nuget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nuget) for some more details.

> - pack
> - push
> - restore

Besides, you want to update the packages in your private nuget repository, you may not be able to easily use nuget or gulp to complete it. According to the [update command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update):

> The update command also updates assembly references in the project
>   file, provided those references already exist. If an updated package
>   has an added assembly, a new reference is not added. New package
>   dependencies also don't have their assembly references added. To
>   include these operations as part of an update, **update the package in
>   Visual Studio using the Package Manager UI or the Package Manager
>   Console**.

So, update the packages without project file/solution file are also not supported by nuget.

Probable, you have to download the latest version of those packages from the nuget.org manually or you can create a powershell script to parse package`s ID for the those packages in your private nuget repository, then use nuget-install in PS script to download the latest version.

Hope this helps.